# in sap fiori application, search bar is working for mock data, not for backend data

Tags: odata, backend, sapui5, searchbar, sap-fiori

in sap fiori application, search bar is working for mock data, not for backend data(sap ABAP(odata))

Filename: Master.Controller.js

```
 onSearch : function() {
            this.oInitialLoadFinishedDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            // Add search filter
            var filters = [];
            var searchString = this.getView().byId("searchField").getValue();
            if (searchString && searchString.length > 0) {
                filters = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("QUARTER_ID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchString) ];
            }
            // Update list binding
            this.getView().byId("list").getBinding("items").filter(filters);

            //On phone devices, there is nothing to select from the list
            if (sap.ui.Device.system.phone) {
                return;
            }

            //Wait for the list to be reloaded
            this.waitForInitialListLoading(function () {
                //On the empty hash select the first item
                this.selectFirstItem();
            });
        },
```

filename: Master.view.xml

```
  <subHeader id="masterSubHeader">
                <Bar id="searchBar">
                    <contentMiddle>
                        <SearchField 
                            id="searchField" 
                           livechange= "onSearch" 
                            width="100%">
                        </SearchField>
                    </contentMiddle>
                </Bar>
            </subHeader>
            <content>
                <List 
                    id="list" 
                    select="onSelect" 
                    mode="{device>/listMode}" 
                    noDataText="{i18n>masterListNoDataText}" 
                    growing="true" 
                    growingScrollToLoad="true" 
                    items="{/quarterviewSet}">
                    <items
                        id="masterList">
                        <ObjectListItem 
                            id="mainListItem" 
                            press="onSelect" 
                            type="{device>/listItemType}" 
                            counter="0" 
                            title="{QUARTER_ID}" 
                            number="{QTRTYPE_NAME}" 
                            numberUnit="{QUARTER_CATEGORY}"
                            markFavorite="false" 
                            markFlagged="false" 
                            showMarkers="false">
                             <attributes> 
                            <ObjectAttribute id="ATTR1" text="{LOCATION}" />
                            <ObjectAttribute id="ATTR2" text="{CITY}" />
                        </attributes> 
                            <core:ExtensionPoint 
                                name="extListItemInfo"/>
                        </ObjectListItem>
                    </items>
                </List>
            </content>
```

Comment: there may be bug in odata implementation in sapui5 or odata service  ,you can use sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ instead of sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains.If you use EQ you need to search whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to figure out if the data from the backend is same as the mock data. If not, the bindings might have gone wrong. Please check if the data is loaded into the list initially with all the backend data. After that, try to do the search. 
Put a break point in the `onSearch` function and see if the data is still there and how if the filters are created.